# Restlet + Google App Engine + CORS

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, cors, restlet

I am using Restlet on Google App Engine for developing my sample application.
The front end is Angular 2 App.

The Rest API is working fine with browser.
However, I am getting the following issue when I am trying to hit the URL from Angular app.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://1-dot-jda-saas-training-02.appspot.com/rest/projectsBillingInfo/123. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://evil.com/, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So, I thought I will go ahead and add the CORS headers in the response. I used CorsFilter for that as follows but the issue is still there. When I see the header of the Response, I do not see any CORS headers. What am I missing here?

```
@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {



    // Create a router Restlet that routes each call to a
    // new instance of HelloWorldResource.
    Router router = new Router(getContext());


    CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter(getContext(), router);
    corsFilter.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("*")));
    corsFilter.setAllowedCredentials(true);
    // Defines only one route
    router.attachDefault(AddressServerResource.class);
    router.attach("/contact/123",ContactServerResource.class);
    router.attach("/projectsBillingInfo/123",ProjectBillingResource.class);
    return corsFilter;
```

}

---

### EDIT

I could get this working. May be I was doing some mistake.
But, I am not able to make this work with the GaeAuthenticator. When I am putting the GaeAuthenticator along with Corsfilter, it skips the authentication part of it. So, either the authentication works or the corsfilter works but not both. Is there any easy way to set/modify HTTP headers in restlet.

Here is the code I am using  ..

```
   @Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {



    // Create a router Restlet that routes each call to a
    // new instance of HelloWorldResource.
    Router router = new Router(getContext());        

    // Defines only one route
    router.attachDefault(AddressServerResource.class);
    router.attach("/contact/123",ContactServerResource.class);
    router.attach("/projectsBillingInfo/123",ProjectBillingResource.class);

    GaeAuthenticator guard = new GaeAuthenticator(getContext());
    guard.setNext(router);



    CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter(getContext(), router);
    corsFilter.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("*")));
    corsFilter.setAllowedCredentials(true);
    return corsFilter;
```

Comment: It's working fine. I need to use the GaeAuthenticator to initialize the CorsFilter not the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you can use the service instead of the filter:

```
public MyApplication() {
    CorsService corsService = new CorsService();
    corsService.setAllowedCredentials(true);
    corsService.setSkippingResourceForCorsOptions(true);
    getServices().add(corsService);
}
```

Do you mind to set the "skippingServerResourceForOptions"?

```
@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    // Create a router Restlet that routes each call to a
    // new instance of HelloWorldResource.
    Router router = new Router(getContext());

    // Defines only one route

    router.attachDefault(AddressServerResource.class);
    router.attach("/contact/123",ContactServerResource.class);
    router.attach("/projectsBillingInfo/123",ProjectBillingResource.class);
    return router;
}
```

Best regards, Thierry Boileau

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What is the advantage of the Service over the Filter? I forgot to mention, it is working fine without the GaeAuthenticator. When I add the GaeAuthenticator, it skips the authentication part of it altogether. Please see the edited question.

Comment: @thierry-boileau, Facing the same issue, if I call getApplication() in createInboundRoot I am getting NULL. Neither am I getting the headers I add in the CORSService

Comment: The service applies to the whole application (it actually relies on an instance of the CorsFilter), and simplifies your code. The filter is much more flexible and can be added in a more precise way.

Comment: @Atrix1987, I've retried today, and it works fine for me. using the the following jars (org.restlet.ext.gae.jar  org.restlet.ext.servlet.jar  org.restlet.jar) taken from the latest 2.3 version for the framework (https://restlet.com/downloads/current/).